# ggplot2 pie chart : Repositioning ggrepel slice labels by moving them toward circumference of the pie possible?

Tags: r, ggplot2, pie-chart, ggrepel

I am trying to create a pie chart of a following data.table obj by using ggplot2;

```
> pietable
                       cluster N P p
     1:                      1 962 17.4  8.70
     2:                      3 611 11.1 22.95
     3:                     10 343  6.2 31.60
     4:                     12 306  5.5 37.45
     5:                      8 290  5.2 42.80
     6:                      5 288  5.2 48.00
     7:                      7 259  4.7 52.95
     8:                     18 210  3.8 57.20
     9:                      4 207  3.7 60.95
    10:                      9 204  3.7 64.65
    11:                     16 199  3.6 68.30
    12:                     17 201  3.6 71.90
    13:                     14 174  3.1 75.25
    14:                     22 159  2.9 78.25
    15:                      6 121  2.2 80.80
    16:                     21 106  1.9 82.85
    17:                      2 101  1.8 84.70
    18:                     26  95  1.7 86.45
    19:                     11  89  1.6 88.10
    20:                     24  84  1.5 89.65
    21:                     32  71  1.3 91.05
    22:                     13  65  1.2 92.30
    23:                     38  50  0.9 93.35
    24:                     25  41  0.7 94.15
    25:                     36  36  0.7 94.85
    26:                     20  39  0.7 95.55
    27:                     28  33  0.6 96.20
    28:                     23  30  0.5 96.75
    29:                     31  24  0.4 97.20
    30:                     15  21  0.4 97.60
    31:                     34  22  0.4 98.00
    32:                     30  14  0.3 98.35
    33:                     33  19  0.3 98.65
    34:                     40  10  0.2 98.90
    35:                     29  11  0.2 99.10
    36:                     37   9  0.2 99.30
    37:                     19   8  0.1 99.45
    38:                     27   6  0.1 99.55
    39:                     39   6  0.1 99.65
    40:                     35   3  0.1 99.75
```

N is a total count of a particular cluster, P is a proportion , and p is a cumsum of P.

A ggplot2 line to create the pie chart is as follows;

```
ggplot(pietable, aes("", P)) + 
  geom_bar(
    stat = "identity", 
    aes(
      fill = rev(fct_inorder(cluster)))) +
  geom_label_repel(
    data = pietable[!P<1], 
    aes(
      label = paste0(P, "%"),
      y = p1,
      #col = rev(fct_inorder(cluster))
    ),
    point.padding = NA,
    max.overlaps = Inf,
    nudge_x = 1,
    color="red",
    force = 0.5,
    force_pull = 0,
    segment.alpha=0.5,
    arrow=arrow(length = unit(0.05, "inches"),ends = "last", type = "open"),
    show.legend = F
  )+  
  geom_label_repel(
    data = pietable[!P<1], 
      aes(label = cluster,
      y = p1),
      size=2,  
      col="black",
      force = 0,
      force_pull = 0,
      label.size = 0.01,
      show.legend = F
    )+
  scale_fill_manual(values = P40) + 
  coord_polar(theta = "y")+
  theme_void()
```

This generates a pie chart like this;

[image]

Some of the pie slices with extremely small values are not labeled for an obvious reason.

What I'd like to do is to reposition slice labels (in number) by moving them toward circumference of the pie.

An example of the pie chart that I'd like to create looks like this;

[image]

I'd appreciate any suggestions to accomplish this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a *lot* of labeling for one visualization, and you may want to consider a different design.

That said, you can add `nudge_x = 0.33` and `segment.color = 'transparent'` to the relevant geom to adjust the positioning of the labels. Note that in order to make the red arrows align to the nudged black labels, you have to add `aes(after_stat(1.33))` to the red geom, matching the new `nudge_x` parameter of the black geom (+1.0). These lines are marked with `# added` comments in the code below.

I've made some light modifications to your plotting code (you seem to have variables in your workspace that are not available in your post), but this is the general idea:

```
ggplot(pietable, aes("", P)) + 
  geom_bar(
    stat = "identity", 
    aes(
      fill = factor(cluster))) +
  geom_label_repel(
    data = pietable[!pietable$P<1, ], 
    aes(
      label = paste0(P, "%"),
      y = p,
      x = after_stat(1.33) # added
      #col = rev(fct_inorder(cluster))
    ),
    point.padding = NA,
    max.overlaps = Inf,
    nudge_x = 1,
    color="red",
    force = 0.5,
    force_pull = 0,
    segment.alpha=0.5,
    arrow=arrow(length = unit(0.05, "inches"),ends = "last", type = "open"),
    show.legend = F
  )+  
  geom_label_repel(
    data = pietable[!pietable$P<1,], 
    aes(label = cluster,
        y = p),
    size=2,  
    col="black",
    nudge_x = 0.33, # added
    force = 0,
    force_pull = 0,
    label.size = 0.01,
    show.legend = F,
    segment.color = 'transparent' # added
  )+
  coord_polar(theta = "y")+
  theme_void()
```

[image]

And for reference, the data set I worked from:

```
pietable <- structure(list(cluster = c(1, 3, 10, 12, 8, 5, 7, 18, 4, 9, 16, 
17, 14, 22, 6, 21, 2, 26, 11, 24, 32, 13, 38, 25, 36, 20, 28, 
23, 31, 15, 34, 30, 33, 40, 29, 37, 19, 27, 39, 35), N = c(962, 
611, 343, 306, 290, 288, 259, 210, 207, 204, 199, 201, 174, 159, 
121, 106, 101, 95, 89, 84, 71, 65, 50, 41, 36, 39, 33, 30, 24, 
21, 22, 14, 19, 10, 11, 9, 8, 6, 6, 3), P = c(17.4, 11.1, 6.2, 
5.5, 5.2, 5.2, 4.7, 3.8, 3.7, 3.7, 3.6, 3.6, 3.1, 2.9, 2.2, 1.9, 
1.8, 1.7, 1.6, 1.5, 1.3, 1.2, 0.9, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.6, 0.5, 0.4, 
0.4, 0.4, 0.3, 0.3, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1), p = c(8.7, 
22.95, 31.6, 37.45, 42.8, 48, 52.95, 57.2, 60.95, 64.65, 68.3, 
71.9, 75.25, 78.25, 80.8, 82.85, 84.7, 86.45, 88.1, 89.65, 91.05, 
92.3, 93.35, 94.15, 94.85, 95.55, 96.2, 96.75, 97.2, 97.6, 98, 
98.35, 98.65, 98.9, 99.1, 99.3, 99.45, 99.55, 99.65, 99.75)), row.names = c(NA, 
-40L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: I don't see  a "segment.color" argument in geom_label_repel usage.  Also, regarding "This is a lot of labeling for one visualization",  I'd appreciate if you could give me a pointer to make this plot simpler.  Thanks.

Comment: "segment.color" appears to be undocumented (or perhaps is passed as part of the geom's `...` arguments). As for the visualization, I can't really advise on a better solution without knowing what, exactly, you are trying to do.